# WHy does 32-bit address has an addressalbe space of 4G bytes?

Tags: memory

I've looked at other answers, none of them convince me, most people just say because 2^32 = 4GB.

From my understanding, 32 bit address, means that each word is 32 bits long. Thus largest 32bit address can represent is 4294967296, which means a 32bit address can represent 4294967296 Words.

How does this 4294967296 Words translate into 4GB....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conventional PC Memory is divided into bytes, and each address points at a single byte (not a word). Since an address is 32 bits, we can have 2^32 = 4294967296 addresses, or 4294967296 bytes (B).

4294967296 B = 4194304 kB = 4096 MB = 4 GB, if we go by factors of 1024.

Comment: The important point is that each address points at a single **byte**, not a 32-bit **word**.

Comment: @MichaelLiu yes. I've edited my answer to word this explicitly now. Thanks.

Comment: So you are saying.... 32 bit addressing  means, it can point to 2^32 bytes.

Comment: Yes. Each address points to a byte, we can have 2^32 addresses, so we end up with a total of 4 gigabytes.

Answer (score 0):

While CPUs use words internally, they still are able to address individual bytes in memory. Since a single memory address has to fit into a word to allow the CPU to handle it, you can only address up to 4 [GiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte) of memory in a 32 bit system.

Non withstanding these remarks, there are ways to address more memory on a 32 bit processor. In x86 CPUs, this is handled under the [Physical Address Extension (PAE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) moniker. By using more then 32 address lines, you can address more memory. However, since the CPU still has only 32 bit words, you can still only use 4 GiB per page table (which is what the actual applications use).